# How do I escape a Sharepoint column name in Microsoft Graph?

Tags: rest, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-files

I'm performing the following request to update the value of "ExampleColumn#" for a Sharepoint Online item:

PATCH [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site_id}/lists/{list_id}/items/{item_id}](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/%7Bsite_id%7D/lists/%7Blist_id%7D/items/%7Bitem_id%7D)

With the following request body:

```
{
    "fields":{
        "ExampleColumn#": 1
    }
}
```

Returns a 400 bad request error, with the following message:

> "message": "A metadata reference property was found in a JSON Light request payload. Metadata reference properties are only supported in responses"

As I believe Odata requires the "#" symbol to be escaped, I've tried using percent-encoding which I couldn't get to work.

Request Body:

```
{
    "fields":{
        "ExampleColumn%23": 1
    }
}
```

Response:

> "message": "Field 'ExampleColumn%23' is not recognized"

What should I be doing differently in my request body?

Comment: You can use this call `GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/{site-id}/lists/{list-id}/items/{item-id}/fields` to get the fields present for that item and you will see the right column name there how they are modified. In your case For '#' it is converted internally as '_x0023_' that means for your field it becomes 'ExampleColumn_x0023_'. In the same way for space(' ') it converts to '_x0020_'. Please go through this [thread](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/274172/the-x0020-of-the-internal-name-for-a-sharepoint-column)

Comment: Did it work for you?

Comment: Hi, @Shiva-MSFTIdentity, that definitely did work for me, thanks! Was a bit odd as with the request to create those columns initially "ExampleColumn#" is accepted as the api facing name for the column - I assume Sharepoint then converts this to _x0023_ afterwards. Thanks for the help though and the thread to read!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Zak,

Please make sure the field in the request body is the correct internal name of that column. I am able to update a column value in my SPO list via the below request:

[image]

You can get the field internal name through its setting page:

[image]